# Como colocar uma camada transparente sobre o preview da camera?

Tags: android

Meu aplicativo envolve uma activity que tira uma foto. Quando o usuário entrar nessa opção e abrir a câmera, eu gostaria de colocar uma camada intermediária. Algo como um quadrado ou uma "mira" sobre a imagem que aparece na câmera.

Comment: Porque não está clara o suficiente? A mim parece-me bem clara a pergunta do Rafael.

Comment: Quando você diz que seu aplicativo "envolve uma activity que tira foto", você quer dizer que você possui uma `Activity` com um `SurfaceView` e etc, certo? Ou você abre o app de câmera do seu aparelho por uma `Intent`?